# Закрытие консоли при запуске программы

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: написал программу с помощью PyQt5, она отлично работает, с помощью pyinstaller сделал .exe файл, так как буду регулярно пользоваться им, и при запуске экзешника, помимо его открывается консоль. Можно ли как-то заблокировать открытие консоли?

Заранее благодарю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо при сборке добавить флажок `--noconsole`:

```
python pyinstaller.py --noconsole <ваш скрипт>.py
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!